# ReactPHP get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Tags: php, reactphp

I am getting this error code:

> PHP Warning:  get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string
>   given in /phalcon/vendor/clue/block-react/src/functions.php on line 90
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Promise rejected
>   with unexpected value of type  in
>   /phalcon/vendor/clue/block-react/src/functions.php:89 Stack trace:
>
> - 0 /phalcon/vendor/clue/block-react/src/functions.php(198): Clue\React\Block\await(NULL, Object(React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop),
>     NULL)
> - 1 /phalcon/app/tasks/RunTask.php(96): Clue\React\Block\awaitAll(NULL, Object(React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop))

I'm building my promises with the following code:

```
$promises[] = $this->getTrades($rule->id, $exchange->id)
                ->then(
                    function ($trades) use ($handleTrades) {
                        foreach ($trades as $trade) {
                            $handleTrades[] = $trade;
                        }
                    }
                );
```

The function is like this:

```
private function getTrades($rule, $exchange) {
    $deferred = new React\Promise\Deferred();

    //...

    if (empty($trades->count())) {
        $deferred->reject("No trades found for rule $rule");
    } else {
        $deferred->resolve($trades);
    }

    return $deferred->promise();
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Furgas mentioned above I needed to add the error handling function in the promise.

Answer (score 1):

The real reason is `Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException`, not the warning. As [you can see](https://github.com/clue/reactphp-block/blob/master/src/functions.php#L88) the `clue/reactphp-block` library expects an `Exception` in your `reject` function. Try:

```
$deferred->reject(new \Exception("No trades found for rule $rule"));
```

Comment: That removes the above error, now I'm getting

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: No trades found for rule 1 in

I'm not a master of Exceptions yet unfortunately

Comment: Well, that's not a problem we are capable to solve for you, at least with the code you provided. We have no idea what `$trades` is and where is it coming from.

Comment: And you must clarify the problem. Is the problem that `$trades->count()` is 0, or is the problem that you're getting fatal error? If the former, then as I said, we can't help you with that code. If the latter, then you have to handle somehow this exception by adding a second parameter to `then` with a function that will print some message or whatever you want to happen in case of no trades.

Comment: It's indeed when $trades->count() is 0 that it should throw the Exception. Not sure if that helps, but I'll tug around a bit.